# How do I configure an archived Outlook folder

Tags: email, ms-office

Is there a way of configuring an archived folder in Outlook for Mac, one which I can regularly move email into and it is stored on either my hard drive or a remove drive?

So I don't want to go through an export process each time - I want something more day to day like Outlook for Windows

Comment: an automated daily archive?

Comment: No just drag and drop

Comment: do you have a mail box on my mac named archive (or make one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook 2011 for Mac has no native archive function built in.  At my office we use two different methods.

**Method 1:**
Purchase [OEAO](http://www.softhing.com/oeao.html) and follow it's instructions.  This is basically an app that can automatically launch at or after a set time each day then automatically move email older than (or whatever rule) X amount of days from your mailbox to local "On my Computer" folders in Outlook.  This is very handy if you have a hard time remembering to move older emails or, if you're like the majority of our users, have dozens (or more) of folders in your mailbox.

**Method 2:**
This is the free method but it lacks the automatic archiving of OEAO.  The gist of it is that you're exporting your entire mailbox (inbox, sent, etc) and reimporting it to create a perfect archive that you can manually add to over time.

1. Choose File > Export
2. Choose "Outlook for Mac Data File (.olm)"
3. Select the item types (we typically just select Mail) and continue
4. You'll be asked if you want to delete everything after exporting.  We choose no but you might choose yes, this is a personal preference.
5. Specify the location and name of the exported file and click Save.  Outlook will often freeze while doing this, however even though it's unresponsive it IS actually working.  Be patient during this step.
6. Once the export process is complete, click on File > Import.
7. Choose Outlook Data File (.pst or .olm).
8. Select Outlook for Mac Data File (.olm).
9. Find the file that you created in step 5 and click Import.  Again, this step will seem unresponsive until it completes.
10. Click Done once Outlook finishes importing.
11. Expand the "On my Computer" section in the left of Outlook and verify that your mail folders are there.
12. Once you're sure that the email has been copied over to the "On my Computer" section you can now safely remove however many old emails as you desire.
13. Going forward, you can drag/drop emails from your main mailboxes to the corresponding mailboxes in "On my Computer" to copy them to your local archive.  Be sure to go back and then delete them from your main mailbox to free up space in your account.

If the On My Computer directory does not show up on the left panel, click Outlook on the menu, select Preferences, select General under Personal Settings, and uncheck the box for Hide On My Computer folders.

As always, please [leave feedback for Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/product-feedback) about features such as this that you wish to see in future versions of Outlook for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is the terminology.

The Outlook has a "On my Mac" directory.

Those folders and emails reside on your Mac- you could call them Archive.

Consequently they are already archived since they are not obeying the IMAP rules and activity in the email folders (that are online folders).

So, just create a new folder name it Archive (or anything you choose) under the On my Mac, and drag emails from your emails folders under your account(s)and inbox in to it. That action will move the email from its current location (online) to your hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Our office was facing issues due to frequent switching between Macs and the PCs. Our team is badly dependent on Outlook for almost every bit. The cross-platform migrations was not only time-consuming but also often led to loss of emails. 
We tried Mail Backup X for easy transferring between OS platforms. It offered free trial for first 15 days and in the free trial version, we were discovering a new feature, every day. We backed up windows exported mails on Mac. We tried on distributed backup, mirror backup, backup on an external drive, on google drive, almost everything. 
Its been a part of our team since then.

It backs up IMAP clients directly, picks up mails from the Outlook database automatically to the configurd locations.
a must tool if you are dependent on mails. we took the free trial from here:http://www.mailbackupx.com/download.html